# How to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS on external SSD?

Tags: ubuntu

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS from https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi and copied image to external SSD using Raspberry Pi Imager.

When I power Raspberry Pi 4 (2GB), I see rainbow and then screen goes black.

I am able to install and boot Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and Ubuntu Desktop 22.10 on same external SSD.

I am also able to install and boot Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS on microSD card.

What am I missing? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Ubuntu? When I tried to use ubuntu on my Pi, it was lagging a lot. Also, when you mentioned Raspberry Pi 4 **(2GB)** is that the ram, or the amount of storage on the sd card?

Comment: Sorry, I meant amount of storage on the external ssd

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Friendlygabe777. 2GB of RAM.

Comment: No problem. I don't think your raspberry pi has enough ram. Did you check the requirements on the Ubuntu site?

Comment: Yes, 2GB is enough.

Comment: Check the logs of the boot on the SSD. It should be in the root directory: /opt/log/

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was the power supply… I was using a 65W AUKEY PA-B3.

Using official Raspberry Pi USB-C power supply, I am able to install and boot Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS.